# sending mail without postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Thanks for taking the time to look/help me.

I am looking for example to send mail without post back using- Jquery/asp.net.

**The scenario is this:**

> The "contact us" form is located at the bottom of a long site(one page
>   site) if I use the regular approach the page is posting back to the
>   server and then the user is not aware if the mail was sent or not..

**My goal is:**

> sending the mail and then show the user a gesture sign indicating if
>   the mail was sent or not

Can someone please direct me to an example like that ( I tried to find but with no luck )

this is what I came with:(its not working)
can someone please direct me how to solve it?

I also tried with .ashx file instead of WebMethod approach with no luck, there are downs for that approach?(ashx)

**JS**:

```
 $('#btn_contactForm').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = $('#form_contact').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:formData,                   
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "<%=siteUrl %>Index.aspx/SendMail",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.respnseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

**Server side:(index.aspx.cs)**

```
[WebMethod]
public Boolean SendMail()
{
    string firstName = ....;
    string lastName = ....;
    string bName = ....;
    string phone =....;
    string senderEmail = ....;
    string message = ....;

    string eBody = "<div style='direction:rtl;'><b>mail sent from: </b>" + firstName + " " + lastName + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>bName: </b>" + bName + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>mail: </b>" + senderEmail + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>phone number: </b>" + phone + "<br />";
    eBody += "<div style='width:300px;'><b>message: </b>" + message + "</div></div>";

    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("***@gmail.com", "***@gmail.com", "message", eBody);
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try
    {
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
        return true;
        //Response.Redirect("Thankyou.aspx");            
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used handler(and not web service) for sending the mail, see discussion [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1445088.aspx):

**JS:**

```
  //Click on the submit button of the- Contact Form
        $('#btn_contactForm').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var settings = {
                'data': getData(),
                'url': "Handlers/SendMail.ashx",
                'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            };
            sendEmail(settings);
        });

        function getData() {
            var data = {
                'firstName': $('#txt_fName').val(),
                'lastName': $('#txt_lName').val(),
                'phone': $('#txt_phone').val(),
                'bName': $('#txt_bName').val(),
                'fromMail': $('#txt_email').val(),
                'Message': $('#txt_message').val()
            };
            return data;
        }

        function sendEmail(settings) {
            var success = false;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: settings.contentType,
                data: settings.data,
                url: settings.url,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Return True from handler
                    //console.log(data); 
                    alert("success")
                    success = true;
                },
                error: function (data) {
                   // Return False from handler
                   // console.log(data);
                    alert("fail")
                    success = false;
                }
            });
            return success;
        }
```

**SendMail.ashx:**

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // Loads parameters into variables
    string firstName = context.Request.Form.Get("firstName");
    string lastName = context.Request.Form.Get("lastName");
    string phone = context.Request.Form.Get("phone");
    string bName = context.Request.Form.Get("bName");
    string senderEmail = context.Request.Form.Get("fromMail");
    string message = context.Request.Form.Get("message");


    //Used a class for sending the mail- in App_Code folder
    //The method(SendEmail) in that class returns boolean True- success, False- failure 
    bool MailSent = Mail.SendEmail(firstName, lastName, bName, phone, senderEmail, message);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    if(MailSent)
    {
        context.Response.Write("true");
    }else
    {
        context.Response.Write("false");

    }
}
```

**Mail.cs**- Mail.SendEmail()

```
 public static bool SendEmail(string firstName, string lastName, string bName, string phone, string senderEmail, string message)
{
    //  Email sending
    string eBody = "<div style='direction:rtl;'><b>sent from </b>" + firstName + " " + lastName + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>bName: </b>" + bName + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>email: </b>" + senderEmail + "<br />";
    eBody += "<b>phone: </b>" + phone + "<br />";
    eBody += "<div style='width:300px;'><b>message: </b>" + message + "</div></div>";

    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("***@gmail.com", "MailMessage("***@gmail.com", "subject", eBody);
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
        return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have your normal SendEmail method, you just need a WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Boolean SendEMail()
{
    //this is my actual email helper I tested it with
    return BLL.MailHelper.sendEmail("youremail@server.com", "Hello, World", "Subject");
}
```

and then do an ajax POST to this page:

from your HTML:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "SampleMail.aspx/SendEMail",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My `BLL.MailHelper.sendEmail()` method here returns a boolean if the email was sent successfully or not, and you will get the same in your jSon on the success callback function, which you can use to notify the user if the email was sent or not.

Notice that SampleMail.aspx is the name of the page, and SendEMail is the Method name. The data argument is empty, but you could send extra parameters to your method here, although I would not recommend it.

Comment: I have a normal 'SendEmail' function, I didn't understand for what I need 'WebMethod' for? can't it be done without another page that contains 'WebMethod'? can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You cannot send email from the client. The WebMethod is a method that can be called through an Ajax request (which can be executed from the client) and have a value returned to the caller method. Since you won't be able to send the email from the client, that leaves the server to do this work, but you do not want a postback. So the only way I can think (thus the answer) was an asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll write down what I understood from your answer:
in the client side- aspx I have a form- With JQuery I sent the form to webservice 
Boolean SendEMail with no data.. why? how is the data go through? 
my web service(asmx, wcf)=web method(stays on those pages? is it correct)?
is caliing a function that send the mail "BLL.MailHelper.sendEmail()" where does the webmethod is(which file)?
I have 1 aspx file(contains the form), 1 javascript file($.ajax), web method(where), "BLL.MailHelper.sendEmail" where(some cs file)? 
Thanks for being patient- I appreciate it.